# Request work at Postman but Fail with Ruby

Tags: ruby, https, postman

I had tried so many options here and I really don't understand what is going one.

I try this request at Postman, and all works fine:

`https://api.airbnb.com/v1/authorize?client_id=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&username=someemail@test.com&password=secret`

But if I try the same with ruby I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My Ruby request is:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://api.airbnb.com/v1/authorize?client_id=d306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20&username=someemail@test.com&password=secret")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
request["postman-token"] = 'f7cd129c-f7f5-b79a-e829-0ad7f7ebf81f'
request['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'


response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```